# To prove convergence of recursive sequence, $u_{n+1}=1-\sqrt{(1-u_n)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

If $0<u_1<1$, $u_{n+1}=1-\sqrt{(1-u_n)}$. Show that sequence converges to zero.

Firstly we prove that indeed this sequence converges, for which it is sufficient to show that sequence is bounded and monotone.
Regarding boundedness of sequence, $\sqrt{(1-u_n)}>0$, hence $1-\sqrt{(1-u_n)}<1, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence bounded.

But what about monotonicity of this sequence?

$u_{n+1}-u_n=1-\sqrt{(1-u_n)}-u_n$ = $(1-u_n)-(\sqrt{1-u_n})$,

Now since, $u_n<1\implies 1-u_n>0 $,

What next? Square root of number subtracted from that number itself may be both positive and negative depending on whether it's larger than one or less than one.

Comment: There is a slick argument that the sequence is strictly decreasing, assuming that it has been proven that $1$ and $0$ are upper and lower bounds of the sequence.  First, show that $u_2 < u_1.$  Then, assume that $u_n < u_{n-1}$.  This implies that $1 - u_n > 1 - u_{n-1}.$  This then implies that $\sqrt{1 - u_n} > \sqrt{1 - u_{n-1}}$.  This implies that $$u_{n+1} = 1 - \sqrt{1 - u_n} < 1 - \sqrt{1 - u_{n-1}} = u_n.$$

Comment: why down vote on question?

Comment: Good question.  I would never downvote a question with the work that you showed.  Unfortunately, there is no quality control on downvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check (by induction) that $0 <u_n<1$ for all $n$. If $x=1-u_n$ then $\sqrt x >x$ because $0 <x<1$. Hence, $u_{n+1}-u_n=x-\sqrt x <0$ and $(u_n)$ is decreasing.

The limit $u$ of $(u_n)$ satisifes the equation $u=1-\sqrt {1-u}$  and this gives $u=0$ or $u=1$. But $u_n\in (0,1)$ is decreasing so the limit cannot be $1$. Hence, $u=0$.